# Failing installation of Mysql

Tags: 12.04, mysql

```
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     Errors were encountered while processing:
  mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have been trying to install this for a while.  I've totally purged the system of anything mysql and tried a reinstall multiple times.  I'm at my wits end.
I'm sure I've forgot to post something you need to troubleshoot it so please ask and I will deliver.

Comment: Me too, exact same issue - after installing 341 update packages (had not used this Ubuntu installation for a while). Also see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/1103837

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I had to change default-character-set=utf8 to character-set-server=utf8

See http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/tag/mysql-5-5/